# AWS S3 static file access works on local but not production

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku

I have setup a AWS S3 bucket for both my static and media files but it currently only works on local host but not when I try on gunicorn or when I deploy to Heroku.

When I take a look at the network information on local host I can see the network is attempting to access the files from "https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/static/image.png". However, when I try this on gunicorn or heroku it is attempting to serve the files from "https://none.s3.amazonaws.com/static/image.png".

I am unsure why it is using 'none' instead of 'mybucketname' and my settings are below.

```
settings.py

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxxx.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1',]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
xxx,
'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
xxx,
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-east-1"


AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'src.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

# Configure Django App for Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
```

If it's relevant my AWS s3 settings are set for '*' allowed hosts, public access is enabled for everything and my IAM account has full s3 access enabled.

Any help much appreciated - have been following this guide https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: How are you passing the environment variables that you are populating from os.environment.get once you are executing this on gunicorn?, have you tried to debug the content of the AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME?

Comment: @Ikaro0 - Using dotenv and it is correctly loading smtp keys stored in the same env file as the AWS information, as I am getting broken link errors emailed through. Tried putting the info directly into the settings file so, AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com'. Still getting 'none'. 

Is my bucket name sensitive information? Should I continue storing this in the env rather than hard coding it into the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ikaro0 ended up being correct. The os.environment.get I was using (dotenv) was causing some issue, only reading some of the environment file. Worked after switching to python-decouple.